# How to import Lanterna package to Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, package, lanterna

I'm a programmer with little knowledge about programming, but I wanted to import the package for Lanterna (a gui console library) called `com.googlecode.lanterna.terminal`
But when I do

```
import com.googlecode.lanterna.terminal;
```

It says it resolved to a package and not a type.

I'm not sure if I even put the .jar file in the right place... Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the lanterna package.

In Eclipse select your project and right click properties-->go to libraries--->add jar file--->select lanterna jar file

Comment: Thanks. yeah... I'm a noob XD